# how to generate dynamic parametrized unit test cases for c# application in vs 2012

Tags: c#-4.0, pex

I explored Pex , code digger for generation of unit test cases by exploring the code but found certain limitations in them .code digger requires portable class libraries whereas Pex requires vs 2010 . I need to know is there any tool to generate the unit test cases automatically for c# applications just like pex do or better than that that can be used with vs 2012 .

regards
priya

Comment: Code Digger no longer requires the exclusive use of portable class libraries. Just turn on the option "DisableCodeDiggerPortableClassLibraryRestriction"